# Check if array column contains any value from a query array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the column `names VARCHAR(30) ARRAY NOT NULL` and I want to query using a list of names, and return rows where the `names` column has values which are also in my query list.

`names` for a certain row will look like: `{margret,susan,karen,daren}`

Right now I can select using contains and one value

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE names @> '{"john"}';

^Returns the rows where names array contains john. (As intended).
```

Everything I try querying using multiple values (ex: `john', 'doe', 'jane') results in errors... here is what I tried and the corresponding errors:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE names @> ANY('{"john", "jane"}');

^ERROR:  could not find array type for data type character varying[]
```

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE names @> ANY('{"john", "jane"}'::varchar(40));

^ERROR:  op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

```
create table testarr(names varchar(10)[] );
insert into testarr values(array['margaret','susan','karen','daren']);
select * from testarr where names && '{"margaret","john"}';
select * from testarr where names && '{"mary","john"}';
```

Result:

```
postgres=# create table testarr(names varchar(10)[] );
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into testarr values(array['margaret','susan','karen','daren']);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from testarr where names && '{"margaret","john"}';
            names
------------------------------
 {margaret,susan,karen,daren}
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from testarr where names && '{"mary","john"}';
 names
-------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Yes, I think I need to study SQL some more, that was super simple.  Thank you.